# simulate Document in Xcode 6

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode6

There used to be a pretty nifty command in xcode 5 where you could simulate the document. I mean when you pressed this option, only the UI of the app got loaded and then you can just see how the autolayout is working.

I forgot where this is and I'd upgraded to Xcode 6.0. COuld anyone help me where this option is in xcode?

Comment: Refer to the following question: [Is “Simulate Interface” gone in Xcode 6.0.1?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25950352/is-simulate-interface-gone-in-xcode-6-0-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is gone. There's no way to get it back.
However, you can instead preview .xib or storyboard files in assistant editor. This dose not open a new window, however, the storyboard file shows the UI preview by default.

[image]